# Jacobson-Morozov Theorem to Produce a One-Parameter Subgroup

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

> Let $X\in\frak{sl}_2(\Bbb{R})$ be nilpotent. Prove that there is a one parameter subgroup $\lambda:\Bbb{R}^\times\rightarrow\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb{R})$ such that $\mathrm{Ad}(\lambda(t))\cdot X = t^2X$ for all $t\in\Bbb{R}^\times$.

Naturally my first thought was to look at the matrix exponential. Since $X$ is nilpotent by Jacobson-Morozov $X$ is in some $\frak{sl}_2$-triple, $(X,Y,Z)$. Suppose that $[Z,X]=2X$. Then we consider the map $t\mapsto\exp(tZ)$. Note that for all $t$, $\lambda(t)\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb{R})$ since
$$
\det(\exp(X))=\exp(\mathrm{tr}(X))
$$
Which in our case will give $\exp(0)$ since $Z\in\frak{sl}_2$. Now making use of the identity
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Ad}(\exp(tZ))\cdot X &= \exp(\mathrm{ad}(tZ))\cdot X \\
&= X + [tZ,X] + \frac1{2!}[tZ,[tZ,X]] + \frac{1}{3!}[tZ,[tZ,[tZ,X]]] + \cdots
\end{align*}
$$
We can simplify this to get a series,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^{k}t^k}{k!}X
$$
Which clearly isn't $t^2X$. I've spent the better part of a week on this problem, I know that Jacobson-Morozov is important here, and I have a hunch some sort of matrix exponential type argument will work but I can't seem to put the pieces together.

My initial hope was that I'd be able to use the nilpotency of $X$ to get that the powers of $X$ vanish and I'd be able to do some cancellation, but the powers of $X$ don't grow in the series. I am pretty new to Lie groups/algebras and adjoint type arguments so sorry if there is an elementary solution, but any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your approach is way too complicated. Rather use standard linear algebra: conjugate $X$ to an upper triangular matrix and argue in this special case.

Comment: @YCor you learn all sorts of new tools you forget about the tried and tested ones on your belt. Embarrassingly simple answer, thanks for pointing it out. However, the hint in the actual paper suggests this follows from Jacobson-Morozov, and I don't see how it applies when we do it this way do you have any idea what the author could have had in mind?

Comment: But the Jacobson-Morozov theorem is here to reduce to the $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ case. If you're already in $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ it makes little sense to use it.

Comment: @YCor: To be fair, it still has a use in that setting, as it roughly says you can consider any nilpotent element as if it were $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg but in dimension 2 any nonzero nilpotent element is conjugate (by some element of $GL_2$) to this matrix ($E_{12}$), in this case the Jacboson-Morozov theorem is just a trivial linear algebra application.